# Why choose 見てからでないと in this question?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verbs, word-usage

I came across the following question when preparing for the N2 exam:

> マンションを買うときは実際に＿、心配だ。
>
> a 見た上で b 見て以来 c 見てからでないと

I thought the answer is a but it's given as c.

That doesn't seem to be right since it's explicitly stated that for this construction,

> 後には、否定的な意味の文がくる

which 心配だ doesn't seem to fit.

Is the answer wrong or maybe I didn't understand the sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I'm not entirely sure why you think

> 後には、否定的な意味の文がくる

Doesn't fit with option `c` here. This just says that you can expect the grammar in question to be followed by something with a negative meaning; it's not for example suggesting that there has to be a [negative conjugation](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%90%A6%E5%AE%9A%E5%BD%A2) involved. `心配` may literally mean worry, but it's being used here to express the fact that something is a bad idea - which seems negative enough to me.

However, it's kind of a moot point in this case anyway because the other two options don't really make sense.

> マンションを買うときは実際に見た上で、心配だ。
>
> When (someone is) going to buy an apartment, (I) worry about it after (they've) actually seen it. (?)
>
> マンションを買うときは実際に見て以来、心配だ
>
> When (someone is) going to buy an apartment, (I) worry about it since (they've) actually seen it. (???)
>
> マンションを買うときは実際に見てからでないと、心配だ
>
> When (one is) going to buy an apartment, (I) worry about it unless (they are) buying after having seen it.

It's pretty awkward to try and provide direct translations for these sentences because it's impossible to place all these implied subjects without more context, but if it helps you, here is a much more natural English translation for option `c`.

> When shopping for apartments, it's not a good idea to buy something you haven't seen first.

Comment: Can (c) not mean simply “When buying an apartment, I am worried unless I buy it after I see it”, with all implied subjects being 私?

Comment: Sure, it could, although trying to pin down implied subjects in Japanese is tricky. There's no way to be sure without context (sometimes no way even with context), and while the implied subject is often oneself, the main way of speaking generally about people (I.E. "one"/"you" in English) is to omit the subject, which is what this looked like to me.